# Automatically updating a PHP object value based on sum of other object values

Tags: php, oop, pointers

Here is a simplified version of the problem.

```
class A{
public $value = 0;
}
class B{
    public $values;
    public $total = 0;
    function __construct($values) {
        foreach($values as $value){
            $this->values[] = &$value;
            $this->total += $value->value;
        }
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->value = 10;
$b = new A;
$b->value = 20;
$x = new B(array($a, $b));
echo $x->total . "\r\n";
$b->value = 40;
echo $x->total;
```

The output is:

```
30
30
```

I want the total to be automatically updated to 50 without iterating on the array and recalculating the sum. Is it possible using PHP pointers?
Desired Output:

```
30
50
```

Comment: Are you interested in a solution, that can do inside the classes whatever neccessary, or does it have to use pointers?

Comment: Any solution that can do the job. Not specific to classes. Just need this for optimizing an algorithm

Comment: *"Is it possible using PHP pointers?"* -- PHP doesn't provide pointers. Wherever you learned about PHP pointers, drop that source; it is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sums cannot change if there origins change. This information is lost. However you can use the magic `__set` method to add additional logic to plain setting. There you can call the "calculator" to change the total.

If you do not need to keep the previous interface, you should use a real setter for value (`setValue`) to achieve this, as `__set` is not good practice.

For example:

```
class A
{
    private $value = 0;
    private $b;

    public function setObserver(B $b)
    {
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name == 'value') {
            return $this->value;
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if ($name == 'value') {
            $prev        = $this->value;
            $this->value = $value;

            if ($this->b instanceof B) {
                $this->b->change($prev, $this->value);
            }
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    public $total = 0;

    public function __construct($values)
    {
        foreach ($values as $v) {
            if ($v instanceof A) {
                $this->total += $v->value;
                $v->setObserver($this);
            }
        }
    }

    public function change($prevValue, $newValue)
    {
        $this->total -= $prevValue;
        $this->total += $newValue;
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
30 
50
```

Comment: But if I call this function then it will iterate on the array every time which defeats the purpose of the question actually. I dont want to iterate on the values more than once. Basically looking for an optimization

Comment: @Abdul: How about now?

Comment: Although it works fine, but for the optimization point of view. It somehow performs the same for me. Thanks anyway for the help.